# How to create django class from exist table

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have `Django` project and I want to migrate one table (that table isn't defined like a `Django` class in `model.py`, but it is exist in `PostgreSQL` DB) from `PostgreSQL` to Django.

Which instrument can be used to create class from exist table in Database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [auto generate models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/legacy-databases/#auto-generate-the-models) with:

```
$ python manage.py inspectdb
```

in order to save the output to a file:

```
$ python manage.py inspectdb > models_from_db.py
```

read [inspectdb](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-inspectdb) for more detail.

You can get generate for just one table passing the table name to the command:

```
$ python manage.py inspectdb table > models_from_db.py
```

Comment: @RaydelMiranda if I will to initiate inspectdb, whole database will generated in one models.py file? Could I to startapp in my project and to generate one particullary class from one particullary table from databast?

Comment: @Tyomik_mnemonic I add such case at the end if you want the command output to be appended to your existing models.py use `>>` instead of  `>`.

Comment: @RaydelMiranda I need it for event, when I have some classes in model, and whant generate class from one particulary table (many to many table) from exist database..